# Any way to quickly find out from what Javascript file and code line a custom event is dispatched?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I would like to be able to find the JavaScript file and code line from which a custom event is dispatched.

Let's say we have two JavaScript files, A.js and B.js. I define and dispatch a custom event from A.js at line X. I listen for it in B.js at line Y.

I could jump into Chrome DevTools and run `monitorEvents($0)` to find out where the event was 'heard' (where the eventListener is in my code base, namely: line Y of B.js). But is there a similarly quick way to find out where the event was dispatched from (namely line X from A.js)?

Comment: Does setting a breakpoint and looking at the stack trace not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in the event listener, create a `new Error` - the second line in its `.stack` property is the source of the event dispatch - note, second line in Firefox, third line in Chrumium based bruisers.

note: `stack` property of an `Error` is "non-standard" - however it's available in every modern browser released in the last 7 years (or older in most cases), and even in IE10

```js
// Chrum browsers stack starts at the second line
const fixChrum = +(new Error().stack.split('\n')[0].startsWith('Error'));

window.addEventListener('custom:event', () => {
    console.log('dispatched from', new Error().stack.split('\n')[1 + fixChrum]);
});
// the following is not required, it just shows the line number before the dispatch
console.log('dispatched from next line', new Error().stack.split('\n')[0 + fixChrum]);
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('custom:event'));
```

Comment: @Bergi - please stop breaking my answer - I use FIREFOX ... not CHRUM

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work for me though. Your version logs "`dispatched from next line Error`" and "`dispatched from     at https://stacksnippets.net/js:13:36`" for me. I'm using Vivaldi 5.3.2679.61, like Chrome/102.0.5005.136.

Comment: They really should properly [standardise `error.stack`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-error-stacks) :-)

Comment: Maybe if you pass a message, it will add a first line in FF as well?

Comment: @Bergi ... lol standardise

Comment: @Bergi - I put in a "fix" - and no, `new Error("something")` doesn't help

Comment: @Bergi - oh. There IS a proposal for a standard! Nice

Comment: Works for me. Just `console.log(new Error().stack)` works well -- nice and short.